# How can I call a specific column of a photo model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, call, photo

I have a photo model and a room model and I am using the paperclip gem with active admin. In the photo model I have two columns "image" and "smallimage". I want to use the "smallimage" on the room index view for performance reasons and the "images" on the room show view. Everything works perfect with activeadmin but  I have issues to call the correct column.

Everything worked perfectly with only the image column. I have treid multiple things but somehow I can't call a the correct column and get always error mesaages. If you need further information just let me know. Any hints much appreciated!

**1) How can I call only the smallimage on the index(room) view?**

**2) How can I call only the image column on the show(room) view?**

**index.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <% @rooms.where(:active => true).each do |room| %>
        <%= link_to room_path(room) do %>
            <div><%= image_tag room.photos[0].image.url(:thumb) if room.photos.length > 0 %></div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <% if @photos %>
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<%= photo.id %>"></li>
         <% end %>
     </ol>
   <% end %>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <% if @photos %>
         <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
            <div class="item <%= 'active' if photo.id == @photos[0].id %>">
               <%= image_tag photo.image.url() %>
            </div>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
  before_action :set_room, only: [:show]

  def index
    sort = params[:sort]
    sort = nil unless sort.in?(['address', 'listing_name', 'nightly_price', 'nightly_price desc', 'reviews'])
    @rooms = Room.order(sort).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
  end

  def show
    @photos = @room.photos

    @booked = Reservation.where("room_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @room.id, current_user.id).present? if current_user

    @reviews = @room.reviews
    @hasReview = @reviews.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) if current_user
  end

  private
    def set_room
      @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "room_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "smallimage_file_name"
    t.string   "smallimage_content_type"
    t.integer  "smallimage_file_size"
    t.datetime "smallimage_updated_at"
    t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_photos_on_room_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "listing_name"
    t.string   "accommodation_type"
    t.integer  "persons"
    t.integer  "property"
    t.integer  "living_area"
    t.text     "rooms_total"
    t.text     "features_short"
    t.string   "pets"
    t.string   "smoking"
    t.string   "check_in"
    t.string   "check_out"
    t.string   "location"
    t.text     "nearby_distance"
    t.text     "features_long"
    t.text     "detailed_description"
    t.text     "house_rules"
    t.string   "address"
    t.text     "video"
    t.integer  "nightly_price"
    t.integer  "hourly_price"
    t.text     "detailed_price"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end

  add_foreign_key "photos", "rooms"
```

Comment: Won't `<%= image_tag photo.smallimage.url() %>` work? Or `<%= image_tag room.photos[0].smallimage.url(:thumb) %>`

Comment: Are you sure this problem can't be solved by using paperclip styles to save a smaller version of the main image?

Comment: @NickM No it does not work but thanks for trying to help me! I guess I have to create an additional model right?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I am not 100% sure but logically I think that it takes more performance to lower the quality for each picture by the gem than just to use a smaller and lower quality picture by default.

Comment: @trickydiddyPaperclip works with ImageMagick to provide multiple resolutions and formats at the time that the original picture is saved. It's very flexible -- if you need another style, or want to change the resolution of any of the styles, you modify the model and call image.reprocess! -- works very well.